# How should I define a closed predicate?

Tags: z3

I'm interested in proving the validity of statements with respect to some hypotheses.  However, it seems by default Z3 assumes an "open" model.  For example, say we assume

foo(4)

and I'd like to show with respect to this statement that things "in" foo are even.  So I start by declaring foo

```
(declare-fun foo (Int) Bool)
```

Next, because I'm interesting in a hypothetical. I construct an implication:

```
(implies (foo 4) (not (exists ((x Int)) (and (foo x) (not (= (mod x 2) 0))))))
```

Finally, because I'm interested in validity, rather than satisfiability, I want to check the unsatisfiability of the negation of this statement.

```
(assert (not (implies (foo 4) (not (exists ((x Int)) (and (foo x) (not (= (mod x 2) 0))))))))
(check-sat)
```

However, Z3 reports that this statement is indeed satisfiable:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun x!0 () Int
    (- 1))
  (define-fun foo ((x!1 Int)) Bool
    (ite (= x!1 4) true
    (ite (= x!1 (- 1)) true
      true)))
)
```

I roughly understand what is going on here, but I'm not sure how to best express that foo should be "closed" under my hypothetical statements.  For this very simple example, I can do so by telling Z3 that there are no other members of foo:

```
(assert (not (implies (and (foo 4) (not (exists ((x Int)) (and (not (= x 4)) (foo x))))) (not (exists ((x Int)) (and (foo x) (not (= (mod x 2) 0))))))))
```

However, as I move to more complex hypotheses it seems like it will become difficult to automatically generate the formulas to define those things that are not in foo.

Is there something silly I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Why not state that (foo x) if and only if x = 4?
Your first statement says (after decompiling negations):

```
(assert (foo 4))
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (and (foo x) (not (= (mod x 2) 0))))
```

That is satisfied by a function foo that maps everything to 'true', 
and the existential assertion can be satisfied using x = -1.
This is standard first-order semantics.

One way of saying that foo is at most satisfied at 4 is:

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (foo x) (= x 4))))
```

You can also say that foo holds only at 4:

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (foo x) (= x 4))))
```

Comment: Thanks, a few weeks ago it occurred to me that using iff was probably the solution.  However, I had been hoping for maybe a flag or some such. In my context there may be many implications defining a predicate, and merging them all into a single iff will require some non-trivial transformations of my source logic.